# Error Setting Python Plugin on Eclipse: Using an Unsupported version (Python and JPython)

Tags: python-3.x, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I was adding a Python plugin to Eclipse. I was able to successfully add PyDev. However, when I was adding manually the interpreter I got the following error:

-Using an unsupported version
(Python and JPython require at least version 2.1 and IronPython 2.6).

-Specifying an invalid interpreter
(usually a link to the actual interpreter on Mac or Linux)

The Python exe file I am using is python-3.5.1-amd64.exe. How can I fix this error?

Comment: `python-3.5.1-amd64.exe` is an installer - have you run this to actually install python?

Comment: Yes, it python-3.5.1-amd64.exe appears as installed.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Jython 2.7.0 instead of Jython 2.7.1. I had

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31558376)